# Sound doesn't work with the headphones

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have a problem with my Ubuntu (I'm new in Linux), I installed yesterday my laptop (Alienware 15 R2) and all works fine except the sound.

The sound works but as soon as I connect my headphones the system didn't switch the sound to the headphones.  I checked in the sound control and when the headphones are connected the box is empty.

Thanks for you help

[With headphones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbYJ6.png)

Comment: It sounds as if your headphones are controlled by another audio card. How many 'sinks' are reported by the command: `pacmd list-sinks` ? Does the output show a `ports:` section?

Comment: PS... I have a Lenovo Thinkpad that also does switch audio to headphones, after some search I found out the hardware switch inside the laptop is broken. You may want to check that too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you performed updates?

To update  system software open up a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) and run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It will ask you for your password iand you'll have to confirm downloads.

After that I'd check for additional drivers. Type this the following or just open the tab in the software center.

```
software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4
```

Sometimes there are updates available for your audio drivers.